# CONTINUOUS ERROR: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Users\NoteBook\Downloads\Compressed\sdktools]

Tags: android-emulator, windows-10, android-sdk-tools

I have tried all the solutions on stackoverflow but it didn't help It keeps to show. What should the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` set to? I want to run the android emulator  I have installed platform-tools and system-images and licences.

This is my SDK directory:

[image]

Comment: Have you already checked your `Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK` settings in Android Studio?

Comment: I don't have android studio. It's just android sdk

Comment: Any response. Anyone can help.

Comment: I am in the same state. Not using android studio. Just the android sdk. Tried setting different paths to the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, but keeps complaining "PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/home/iseries/]!" @sporttv, were  you able to resolve this eventually? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` to the path of the `.android` directory.
Usually this folder is located inside your user directory.

Comment: Tried that too. "export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/username/.android/", but didnot help. I am not using android-studio, but only the SDK.